# IProxyService.setProxyData affects system properties

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy, eclipse-plugin

In a test, I'm trying to programmatically change the Eclipse proxy settings without directly affecting the `System` properties.

My current attempt is as such:

```
    httpProxyData.setHost(host)
    httpProxyData.setPort(port)
    httpProxyData.setUserid(userId)
    httpProxyData.setPassword(password)

    proxyService.setProxyData((IProxyData[]) [
        httpProxyData
    ])
```

My proxy service settings are as follows:

```
    proxyService.setProxiesEnabled(true)
    proxyService.setSystemProxiesEnabled(false)
```

When `proxyService.setProxyData` executes, `System.getproperty("http.proxyHost")` is immediately changed to `host`.
The [IProxyService API](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fnet%2Fproxy%2FIProxyService.html) states that `System` properties will not be affected. I want it such that the `System` properties are only affected by me setting `System.setProperty(..., ...)` at a later or earlier time.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc says 'doesn't affect settings of the system proxies' - I think they mean it does not change the settings in the operating system.

Looking at the code it always call `System.setProperty` (which only sets the property for the current JVM).

Comment: Thanks greg-449. What code are you referring to? I've looked at `ProxyManager`, but I can't find anything the sets the system properties.

Comment: `org.eclipse.core.internal.net.ProxyType`. It actually calls `System.getProperties` and manipulates the returned Properties.

Comment: Interesting. In a fresh project, when I set the Eclipse proxy settings in the preferences (through the UI), then create a program that queries something like `System.getProperty("http.proxyHost");`, it returns `null`. Do you happen to know if using the UI invokes something along the lines of `proxyService.setProxyData`?

Comment: If you run a separate program it will be running in a different JVM so won't get the system properties set in the Eclipse JVM.